# Rebound library facebook

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying to use this library, and I noticed there is a configuration panel you can add in the xml :

```
 <com.facebook.rebound.ui.SpringConfiguratorView
    android:id="@+id/spring_configurator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
```

which affects this code:

```
SpringSystem springSystem = SpringSystem.create();

// Add a spring to the system.
Spring spring = springSystem.createSpring();

// Add a listener to observe the motion of the spring.
spring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {

  @Override
  public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
    // You can observe the updates in the spring
    // state by asking its current value in onSpringUpdate.
    float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
    float scale = 1f - (value * 0.5f);
    myView.setScaleX(scale);
    myView.setScaleY(scale);
  }
});
```

I'm trying to do the same thing the configuration panel does just without it?
Anyone knows how to do it?
Here is an example of what I want to do  - without the panel : http://facebook.github.io/rebound/

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about how to set the Tension and Friction for your Spring, you have to use `SpringConfig`

In your case you can set the SpringConfig of an individual spring by calling it like so:

```
SpringSystem springSystem = SpringSystem.create();

// Add a spring to the system.
Spring spring = springSystem.createSpring();

// Add a listener to observe the motion of the spring.
spring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {

@Override
public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
    // You can observe the updates in the spring
    // state by asking its current value in onSpringUpdate.
    float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
    float scale = 1f - (value * 0.5f);
    myView.setScaleX(scale);
    myView.setScaleY(scale);
  }
});

// Specify your own TENSION or FRICTION value as an int
SpringConfig config = new SpringConfig(TENSION, FRICTION);
spring.setSpringConfig(config);
```